# Split list into an n x length matrix

Tags: python

Assuming a list as below:

```
Y= [-0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 4.0, 4.0, -0.0, 2.0, -0.0, -0.0, 4.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 4.0, 2.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 4.0, 2.0, 4.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 4.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, 4.0, -0.0, -0.0, 2.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0, -0.0]
```

How this list could be converted to a matrix for each n number. let's say set n=10, the matrix or array is supposed to look like below:

[image: Example of expected output]

Cheers,

Comment: matrix as in numpy array or list of lists?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks)

Comment: Do you want a dataframe with `n_i` columns and `row_j` rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job. This creates a lists of list though.

```py
step_size = 10
steps = range(0, len(Y), step_size)

y = [Y[step:step + step_size] for step in steps]
```

If you want an array:

```py
import numpy as np

n = 10

y = np.array(Y).reshape(-1, n)
```

Yields:

```py
[[-0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0.  4.  4. -0.  2.]
 [-0. -0.  4. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0.  4.  2.]
 [-0. -0. -0.  4.  2.  4. -0. -0. -0. -0.]
 [ 4. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0.]
 [-0.  4. -0. -0.  2. -0. -0. -0. -0. -0.]]
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi what you can do is

`list = [ [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,],[....],...,[...]]`
These are nested list where each internal list is a row and 1colume

Comment: In java they are called mulitdemtional array

Comment: You can use a loop to make a matrix